# Why can users no longer update their own billing/credit card details in CiviCRM? Using iATS Payments

Tags: civicontribute, iats

Payment processor objects can implement the CiviCRM Core method updateSubscriptionBillingInfo to implement payment-processor specific code to update card-on-file type information with the payment processor service, for recurring payments.

iATS Payments Extension did/does just that and thus allowed people to update their own billing/credit card details for recurring contributions. Why is this no longer working?

Answer (score 2):

If you have been using this feature you may have noticed this is no longer working in higher 5.x versions of CiviCRM. This regression can be fixed with this solution (PR) which was posted here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12668 - unfortunately it was closed. If this feature is important to you - all you need is to add one-line of code (highlighted in green) to this file: CRM/Contribute/Form/UpdateBilling.php

[image]

**UPDATE:** As a work around, there's now a patch to the iATS extension which will ship with the next release. It's not a great solution, but easier for most people than patching core